# EventLog name in other languages

Tags: script, language, event-viewer

I'm writing a script that can pick up installations for a particular vendor from EventLog. I've got a particular problem that in OS versions other than English language both the name of the Event Viewer and log name "Applications" are in local language..

QUESTION 1
I would need to know both of these for the majority of European languages, including all the scandinavian languages, German, French, Spanish and Italian. can anyone help in just checking theirs?

QUESTION 2
Does anybody know of a Microsoft translation or naming phrasebook or resource online?

regards
Mikko

Answer (score 0):

#### Does anybody know of a Microsoft translation or naming phrasebook or resource online?

Yes, the [Microsoft Language Portal](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/language).

You can search for any **Terminology** phrase and it will give you the translation for a chosen language.

Unfortunately you can only get one translation at a time using the web interface.

If you have an MSDN subscription then there are [Translations of the user interface text (UI strings) for Microsoft products and services](https://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Translations.aspx) available for download.

---

#### `EventLog` and `Application` in other languages.

Here are the first from the above website. I will leave it as an exercise to retrieve the remaining translations.

```
Language  EventLog                         Application
--------  -------------------------------  -----------
German    EventLog or Ereignisprotokoll    Anwendung
French    Journal des événements           Application
Spanish   EventLog or Registro de eventos  Aplicación
Italian   Registro eventi                  Applicazione
```

Comment: @MSummala Do you need more help? If this was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to upvote/accept it. See [accept an answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).